# What parameter should I pass to wp_enqueue_style to depend on the themes stylesheet?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, css

I have written a basic [gallery plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bitvolution-image-galleria/) that uses [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to include a stylesheet on the page. I'd like for the WordPress theme to be able to override the style of the plugin which means I'd like to my plugin to play nice and output the css file **before** the theme css file.

[wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) has a `deps` parameter for exactly this requirement. My question is what value should I use for the `deps` parameter if I want to say "I depend on the themes css file"?

The current plugin code is incorrect because it uses `false` for the `deps` parameter:

```
   // Enqueue a CSS style file - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style                                                         
   wp_enqueue_style('bitvol_galleria_css', BITVOL_GALLERIA_URL . '/bitvolution-image-galleria.css', false, $this->bitvol_galleria_version, 'all' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue - you have dependency backwards. Depending on something means loading **after** dependency, while you want earlier.

Second issue - theme's stylesheet doesn't actually use enqueue, it is usually codded directly in `header.php` file of theme. And since it seems to come before `wp_head()` call - you have no hook to ensure your stylesheet is above it.

So this is commonly handled like your [workaround](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/what-parameter-should-i-pass-to-wp-enqueue-style-to-depend-on-the-themes-styleshe/9487#9487) - queued stylesheet with option to disable it by code or option in admin.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd post my workaround which I'm using until I know the answer to the question...

My workaround is:

1. Cut & Paste the CSS code from the plugin, into the theme (i.e. `style.css`) and modify it as needed.
2. Tell the theme to block the plugin from outputing a stylesheet by deregistering it in `functions.php`:

Code to put in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles() {
  wp_deregister_style( 'bitvol_galleria_css' );
}
```

In some respects, this *workaround* could be the better solution? (because the  website performance will be better by minimising the number of CSS resources included in the HEAD section).